# postgresql function to call webservice

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, httpclient, postgresql-extensions

I want to call a webservice from Postgresql function.
I have seen this link where it is shown how to make a http request using pgpsql code
http://boundlessgeo.com/2012/04/http-for-postgresql/

Also shown On Github 
https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http

But how i can add this extension to my PostgresSQL
or
Is there are other approach to call a http service from postgres?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5 Windows version.

Comment: [Procedural Languages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xplang.html) Using `PL/Python` for example it is 2-4 lines of code in the SP body.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's not a windows version of that extension yet. However all is not lost, you could compile it yourself:

http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/

Download the source from the github link you posted originally and apply the instructions in the link.